# php basic script - Undefined variable

Tags: php

Im trying to when an user writes in the search field and submit de value of the submit button change.

First I want the button with value "Search..."

But then, when an user submit form I want to change the button value to "Back..."

Im trying this with code below but Im getting this error:

**Error:** undefined index search

Do you see where the problem is?

```
<form name="searchForm" action="" method="post">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="searchI" class="radius" size="30" value="Search..." 
        onclick="if(this.value=='Search...')this.value=''" 
        onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search...'"
        />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['searchI']) || ($_POST['searchI'] != 'Search...') ){echo 'Back';} else {echo 'Search...';}?>" name="sendForm" class="btn" />
</form>
```

Comment: This code cannot possibly produce that error, because the only place it uses `searchI` is as an array key in $_POST, and is in an isset() call anyways.

Comment: Are you sure the error is complaining about an undefined variable called `$searchI`? It looks like `$search` is undefined, but there is not variable `$searchI`.

Comment: You aren't getting that error. That's not a proper PHP error. So please copy and paste precisely what it's showing rather than retyping it.

Comment: Sorry you were right, I was here try some alternatives and I did the question wrong, I update question with what Im getting now!

Comment: You're almost there! Now you just need to change the second `$_POST['search']`.

Comment: slugonamission thanks, but I already have that right on my php file, but I forget here to put it right. But the script is not working like I want!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can replace `$search` by `$_POST['searchI']`

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php if(isset($_POST['search']) || ($_POST['search'] != 'Search...') )
```

In the above statement, you see if the user searched for something using the `isset` call. If they didn't, you then check `$_POST['search']` anyway due to the semantics of the logical OR operator.

Are you sure you didn't mean to use AND (`&&`) there instead?

Also, as @doydoy44 says, your form field is named wrong, you submit a text box with the name `searchI` and check for a field called `search`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was thinking wrong, I need &&. But now I dont have any error but this basic script its not working!

Comment: @slugonamission : Sorry, I did not see that you answered for && I made a rollback of my answer. you were faster. :) and I up for you ;)

Comment: @CesarM - almost! I just commented on the question, you only changed one of the instances of `$_POST['search']`...you need to change the other one too.